# How to filterfalse pandas dataframe from django queryset

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pandas

This is to add a to a postgres table data from an html table, without having to recreate the table, but simply insert new data.

I need to remove some row from a pandas dataset, those data are already inside the django db and would trow an error triyng to reinsert them in the db. 
So first I look for the rows in the df already archived in the db:

```
items_to_be_removed_from_df=MyModel.objects.filter(id=df['id']).annotate().values(id)


In [42]: x=MyModel.objects.filter(id=df['id']).values('id')

In [43]: x
Out[43]: (0.001) SELECT "tb_storico"."id" FROM "test" WHERE "tb_storico"."id" = '0    2017-10-1707:59:46
1    2017-10-1707:59:46
2    2017-10-1708:26:08
3    2017-10-1707:51:32
4    2017-10-1707:57:23
Name: id, dtype: object' LIMIT 21; args=('0    2017-10-1707:59:46\n1    2017-10-1707:59:46\n2    2017-10-1708:26:08\n3    2017-10-1707:51:32\n4    2017-10-1707:57:23\nName: id, dtype: object',)
<QuerySet []>
```

Now I need to get the other rows from the df, would it be possible something like this?

```
filtered_df=df.filterfalse(id=items_to_be_removed_from_df)
```

The data are transfered by:

```
def insert_data():

    df = read_now()

    MyModel.objects.filter(id=df['id'])

    from django.conf import settings

    user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
    password = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
    database_name = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
    host= settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST']


    database_url = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{database_name}'.format(**vars())

    engine = sa.create_engine(database_url, echo=False)

    df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)

    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
        MyModel(**vals) for vals in df.to_dict('records')
    )
```

Comment: This seems odd: `.filter(id=df['id'])` usually doesn't take a Series object on the right side of the equal sign. How does that line work for you?

Comment: Looping over the dataframe rows, using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) should do what you want: it will only insert data if it doesn't exist yet. Use the `defaults` keyword for information that you do *not* want to match one.